# Rollup bundles files outside of set input

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I am using rollup as a module bundler for my component library and when I run it and target:

```
src/index.ts
```

in the

```
rollup.config.js
```

Everything works fine.

In the root folder of my library, where the rollup.config.js is I have also `example` folder. In this example folder I have projects that are showing example usages of the library and have node_modules too.

I realized that when I break some of the node_modules in the `example/` folder and try to build my library rollup throws an error that it does not find some missing files in the example folders. E.G

[!] (plugin typescript) Error: File 'example/example-proj/node_modules/gl-matrix/types.d.ts' not found.

However, this means that rollup, bundles also my example folders too. But my rollup config targets `src/index.ts` only. And there are no references to the example folders there. Rollup.config.js:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript3'
import packageJson from './package.json'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      format: 'cjs',
      file: packageJson.main,
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      format: 'es',
      file: packageJson.module,
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    external(),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/**'],
    }),        
    typescript({
      clean: true,
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      exclude: ['node_modules'],
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: [autoprefixer()],
      inject: { insertAt: 'top' },
      sourceMap: true      
    }),
  ]
}
```

Some info on how the proj structure looks like:

```
src/index.ts
src/components/
package.json
tsconfig.json
rollup.config.js
example/
example/example-proj/node_module
...
```

This is possibly making my project heavy and also not correct. Why this can happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, I have exactly the same problem. If you found a solution please share